# Align scrollView on Top of the HandleButton of a slidingDrawer

Tags: android-layout, android-xml, android

I am working with a slidingdrawer and a scrollView. The Scrollview is on the top of the screen, and the slidingDrawer at the Bottom. I would like to set the slidingDrawer at the top of the handle button of the scrollView because i don't want the scrollView to take all the screen once open.

This is what i want to get :

[image]

[image]

And this is what i have :

[image]

i would have think of something like this :

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignBot="@id/handle"
    >
```

In order to get this :

[image]

But it's not possible, as he's the child of the slidingDrawer. 
I get the follow error text :

```
@id/handle is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout
```

My question is then : how to get something like the last screen ?

Here's my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- SlidingDrawer -->



<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_slider" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton_HG"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/backgroundBase"
                android:contentDescription="@style/appTitle"
                android:src="@drawable/bouton_note" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton_HD"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/backgroundBase"
                android:contentDescription="@style/appTitle"
                android:src="@drawable/bouton_photo" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton_BG"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/backgroundBase"
                android:contentDescription="@style/appTitle"
                android:src="@drawable/sync_agenda" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton_BD"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/backgroundBase"
                android:contentDescription="@style/appTitle"
                android:src="@drawable/sync_contacts" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>




<!-- ScrollView -->
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Notif1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Notif2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Notif3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Notif4"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Notif5"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Notif6"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Notif7"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView OTHERS TEXTVIEW ... >
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Was my answer helpfull or not??

Comment: I've forget the idea to do this for the moment, but i think AndroidSlidingUpPanel should help me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using same approach in my app with ListView above MapFragment. Fragment and SlidingDrawer are both placed in FrameLayout. Key for you, is to correctly define SlidingDrawer handle: `android:handle="@+id/handle"`

Check out my layout, hope it will help. Also check out following library, it should be perfect for your needs: [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

<SlidingDrawer
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:content="@+id/spotsMap__list"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/handle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/spod_detail_bckg" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/home" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/spotsMap__list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
    </ListView>
</SlidingDrawer>
```